# Making HTTP request with AlamoFire causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm working on a simple project to help learn Swift and I'm running into a problem that I think has deeper implications / learning opportunities (trying to look on the bright side).

**The high-level problem is that when I POST JSON-encoded parameters using AlamoFire, a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error quickly appears in a separate line of code where I set one of the parameters (specifically CoreLocation Manager's "didUpdateLocations") ... here's the code:**

In ViewController, I create a mutable dictionary:

```
var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
```

And, for the `didUpdateLocations` event, I assign the updated latitude / longitude values to the respective keys in the mutable dictionary.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    ...
    func locationManager(locManager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        appDelegate.parameters["longitude"] = locManager.location.coordinate.longitude
        appDelegate.parameters["latitude"] = locManager.location.coordinate.latitude
    }
```

Finally, I have a periodic function (using `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`) that POSTs to a server.

```
func updatePost() {
    println("POSTing update")

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://server.co/endpoint",
            parameters: appDelegate.parameters, encoding: .JSON)
}
```

**If I comment out the Alamofire POST, everything is fine.  *With* the POST, I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the first line of the didUpdateLocations (where the `longitude` key is set)**

I suspect it's something to do with how the parameters are converted by the encoding routine of Alamofire, but I have no idea why it would appear up in the didUpdateLocations function and not in the Alamofire call itself ...

Can anyone provide any insights?  Thank you

Comment: Why are you putting everything in AppDelegate like that? Global shared mutable state is a recipe for EXC_BAD_ACCESS and other ownership errors.

Comment: It was a hold over form something I was trying earlier, but good point.  I just moved `parameters` into ViewController and the same issue is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you have multiple threads trying to access a `Dictionary` at the same time. When you modify `parameters` in `didUpdateLocations`, it likely moves in memory while it's being read inside Alamofire, causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

To solve this I would stop updating the `parameters` dictionary from within `didUpdateLocations` - add a `latestLocation` property to your view controller and update that instead. Then, inside `updatePost`, create your dictionary of parameters and pass it to `Alamofire.request`.

Comment: That makes sense - thank you! Suggested solution worked